# Flink read data from Hadoop and publish to Kafka

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-batch

I have a requirement to read data from HDFS and publish it to a Kafka topic. Because they are part of DataSet and DataStream APIs, is it possible to do what I'm looking for in a single job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink's DataStream API can be used to read from HDFS files. See `readfile()` in https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/datastream_api.html#data-sources. Or you can use the [file system connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connect.html#file-system-connector) with the Table and SQL APIs, but it only supports CSV.